# Присвоение лейблу данных из json

Tags: json, ios, swift

Всем привет. Есть таблица, в каждой ячейке которой 2 лейбла, данные которым присваиваются из файла json. На момент присвоения данных переменная с данными из json оказывается пустой, хотя парсинг и присвоение значения переменной производится во `viewDidLoad`.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    openJSON(city: city)
}


func openJSON(city: City) {
    guard let city = city.name else {return}
    let urlString = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&units=metric&APPID=0732da88478eabca2216d946d5758695"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {return}
        do  {
            guard let weatherData = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherData?.self, from: data) else {return}
            print(weatherData)
            self.allData.append(weatherData)
        } catch let error {
            print("Не удалось сохранить из-за ошибки \(error).")
        }
    } .resume()
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "cellID"
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? WeatherTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("Can't find cell with id:\(cellIdentifier)")
    }
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.update(with: allData[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

После того, как все данные с сервера получены и распашены, стоит обновить таблицу. Не знаю точно, как называется таблица, но примерно это будет выглядеть так:

```swift
func openJSON(city: City) {
    ...                                    // Тут пропущен код и вашего примера
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        ...                                // Тут пропущен код и вашего примера
        DispatchQueue.main.async {         // Переводим выполнение в главный поток
            self.tableView.reloadData()    // Обновляем данные в таблице
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Дополнительно рекомендую сделать `[weak self]`, хотя работать будет и без него.